# How to run a single test with Mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I use Mocha to test my JavaScript stuff. My test file contains 5 tests. Is that possible to run a specific test (or set of tests) rather than all the tests in the file?

Answer (score 505, accepted):

Try using [mocha's `--grep` option](https://mochajs.org/#usage):

```
    -g, --grep <pattern>            only run tests matching <pattern>
```

You can use any valid JavaScript regex as `<pattern>`.  For instance, if we have `test/mytest.js`:

```
it('logs a', function(done) {
  console.log('a');
  done();
});

it('logs b', function(done) {
  console.log('b');
  done();
});
```

Then:

```
$ mocha -g 'logs a'
```

To run a single test. Note that this greps across the names of all `describe(name, fn)` and `it(name, fn)` invocations.

Consider using nested `describe()` calls for namespacing in order to make it easy to locate and select particular sets.

Comment: When using Mocha programmatically (for example from Grunt), there's a catch: grep option needs to be a ´RegExp()´ object. If it's a string, it will be escaped.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. specifying files on the command line (`mocha some/test.js`) didn't work at all. thanks!

Comment: Any way to avoid also running `logs a bcd` which contains the `logs a` substring? Regexp `^$` not working on 0.10.2.

Comment: Thanks.I get some errors if I don't specify directory as mocha -g 'logs a' .

Comment: For any windows users: the test name needs to be double quotes, at least that is what worked for me.

Comment: Yes it works for me      ``npm run test --grep ./test/bootstrap.test.js  ./test/integration/controllers/AccountManagementController-v2.test.js``

Answer (score 227):

Depending on your usage pattern, you might just like to use *only*. We use the TDD style; it looks like this:

```
test.only('Date part of valid Partition Key', function (done) {
    //...
}
```

Only this test will run from all the files/suites.

Comment: BDD works the same. This is great for when you are working on a single test. It can also be used at the suite/describe level

Comment: With chai and expect syntax that would be `it.only`.

Comment: This answer is better since it will also work when mocha is used from inside karma, etc.

Comment: `it.only` will not work together with `given` of [mocha-testdata](https://github.com/pandell/mocha-testdata). And it's easy to forget to remove it later on.

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's easy to forget to remove `.only` when it comes to committing, which might mean only the test subset is run in CI - not good.

Comment: `eslint-plugin-mocha` has a rule `no-exclusive-tests` which will catch you if you forget to remove `.only`.

Comment: Dangerous if tests are are not executed via --forbid-only on the CI / build server. .only has a tendency to sneak into main branch and rendering the other tests mute as they just will not execute anymore. I came to think of the workflow of changing code to run different tests an anti-feature. The test runner should determine which tests should be executed (aka tagged tests) not the developer.

Comment: @k0pernikus The question is a simple one: How do you run a single test in mocha? And the answer is a simple one: By using the `.only` method on the test (`it.only()`). As far as it being "dangerous" to do this, if a team wants to prevent only one test from running on a build server, that can and should be done by setting a code coverage threshold in a configuration file, such as `karma.conf.js`.

Answer (score 126):

If you are using `npm test` (using package.json scripts) use an extra `--` to pass the param through to mocha

e.g. `npm test -- --grep "my second test"`

**EDIT**: Looks like `--grep` can be a little fussy (probably depending on the other arguments). You can:

Modify the package.json:

```
"test:mocha": "mocha --grep \"<DealsList />\" .",
```

Or alternatively use `--bail` which seems to be less fussy

```
npm test -- --bail
```

Comment: @Andy `--grep ` can be a little fussy - try putting it right after mocha within the npm script entry. Else `npm test -- --bail` is useful for bailing after the first failing test

Comment: passing extra dashes before `--grep` saved my day! Thanks a lot. PS. I'm on Windows, running `npm test -- --grep @tag`

Answer (score 93):

Just use .only before 'describe', 'it' or 'context'. I run using "$npm run test:unit", and it executes only units with .only.

```
describe.only('get success', function() {
 // ...
});

it.only('should return 1', function() {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: it.only is not working for me

Answer (score 39):

### run single test –by filename–

Actually, one can also run a single mocha test **by filename** (not just by „it()-string-grepping“) if you remove the glob pattern (e.g. `./test/**/*.spec.js`) from your mocha.opts, respectively create a copy, without:

```
node_modules/.bin/mocha --opts test/mocha.single.opts test/self-test.spec.js
```

Here's my mocha.single.opts (it's only different in missing the aforementioned glob line)

```
--require ./test/common.js
--compilers js:babel-core/register
--reporter list
--recursive
```

**Background:** While you can override the various switches from the opts-File (starting with `--`) you [can't override the glob](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1444#issuecomment-64114261). That link also has
some explanations.

**Hint:** if `node_modules/.bin/mocha` confuses you, to use the local package mocha. You can also write just `mocha`, if you have it installed globally.

---

And if you want the comforts of `package.json`: Still: remove the `**/*`-ish glob from your `mocha.opts`, insert them here, for the all-testing, leave them away for the single testing:

```
"test": "mocha ./test/**/*.spec.js",
"test-watch": "mocha -R list -w ./test/**/*.spec.js",
"test-single": "mocha",
"test-single-watch": "mocha -R list -w",
```

usage:

```
> npm run test
```

respectively

```
> npm run test-single -- test/ES6.self-test.spec.js
```

[mind the `--`](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1444#issuecomment-64114261) which chains whatever text comes after it to the `npm` script

Comment: $1 was not needed in my setup, instead, it lead to warnings like:

`Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: $1`

Answer (score 37):

There are multiple ways by which you can do this.

- If you just want to run one test from your entire list of test cases then, you can write **only** ahead of your test case.

  ```
  it.only('<test scenario name>', function() {
    // ...
  });
  ```

  or you can also execute the mocha grep command as below

  ```
  mocha -g <test-scenario-name>
  ```
- If you want to run all the test cases which are inside one describe section, then you can also write only to describe as well.

  ```
  describe.only('<Description of the tests under this section>', function() {
    // ...
  });
  ```
- If you have multiple test files & you wanted to run only one of then you can follow the below command.

  ```
  npm test <filepath>
  ```

  eg :

  ```
  npm test test/api/controllers/test.js
  ```

  here 'test/api/controllers/test.js' is filepath.

Comment: the `it.only()` syntax is really nifty especially if you don't want to modify your `package.json` (i.e., when the unit test runner is an aliased entry under `"scripts"`) every time you want to change the test case. more context: https://medium.com/@cnadeau_/mocha-running-a-single-test-in-dev-64f2dc509f99

Answer (score 18):

You can try "it.only"

```
it.only('Test one ', () => {
            
    expect(x).to.equal(y);
});

it('Test two ', () => {
            
    expect(x).to.equal(y);
});
```

in this the first one only will execute

Comment: Dangerous if tests are are not executed via `--forbid-only` on the CI / build server. `.only` has a tendency to sneak into main branch and rendering the other tests mute as they just will not execute anymore. I came to think of the workflow of changing code to run different tests an anti-feature. The test runner should determine which tests should be executed (aka tagged tests) not the developer.

Comment: I have used this for testing one functionality in my local,
Note: dont commit code with `it.only` to repo

Answer (score 12):

Hi above solutions didn't work for me. 
The other way of running a single test is

```
mocha test/cartcheckout/checkout.js -g 'Test Name Goes here'
```

This helps to run a test case from a single file and with specific name.

Comment: Use an expression that is selective enough for `-g` and you won't need to specify a file name. If you cannot write an expression that is selective enough, that means that you're not naming your tests properly.

Answer (score 10):

Looking into [the doc](https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage), we see that simply using:

```bash
mocha test/myfile
```

will work. You can omit the '.js' at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Mocha's `--fgrep`](https://mochajs.org/#command-line-usage) (or just -f) you can select tests containing string, for example:

```js
mocha -f 'my test x'
```

will run all tests containing `my test x` in either `it()`, `describe()` or `context()` blocks.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why the grep method is not working for me when using npm test. This works though. I also need to specify the test folder for some reason.

```bash
npm test -- test/sometest.js
```

Answer (score 5):

**For those who are looking to run a single file** but they cannot make it work, what worked for me was that I needed to wrap my test cases in a describe suite as below and then use the describe title e.g. 'My Test Description' as pattern.

```
describe('My Test Description', () => {
  it('test case 1', () => {
    // My test code
  })
  it('test case 2', () => {
  // My test code
  })
})
```

then run

`yarn test -g "My Test Description"`

**or**

`npm run test -g "My Test Description"`

Comment: getting 'Warning: Cannot find any files matching pattern "My Test Description"' and it runs the entire tests

Answer (score 2):

To run a single test with the following form:

```
//file: good.test.js
describe('describeTitle', function() {
  it('itTitle', function() {
    //some assertions
  });
});
```

You can run mocha like this:

```
mocha --grep "^describeTitle itTitle$"
```

And if you have multiple tests in different files that match this pattern `"^describeTitle itTitle$"` you can also specify the file's absolute/relative path, before `--grep` like this: `mocha path/to/good.test.js --grep "^describeTitle itTitle$"`

For example, Consider the following

```js
describe('POST /api/products', function() {
  it('test 1', function() {
    //some assertions
  });
  it('test 2', function() {
    //some assertions
  });
});
```

To run `test 1` you can run mocha like this:

```bash
mocha --grep "^POST /api/products test 1$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate all your tests in one test.js file and add a script in your package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
  "api:test": "node_modules/.bin/mocha --timeout 10000 --recursive api_test/"
},
```

Type this command in your test directory:

```bash
npm run api:test
```

Comment: in package.json, you can just use as 'mocha'. it has not to write node_modules.
when you want to run on CLI, just use prefix 'npx'

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'f' in front of 'it' function that run only a test where you added.

```
fit('should proprerly parse Enums', () => { }
```

Comment: This looks invalid. Use .only(), reference https://mochajs.org/#exclusive-tests